# Explaining sub-queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm finding it difficult learning how to formulate subqueries in MySQL

For example, this code doesnt seem to be working.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE Field NOT IN (
    SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = $table
    AND column_name LIKE 'project_images_%'
);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? or good resources on subqueries?

Comment: I have seen other people ask for resources on various things. And givent that this is a community of developers I assumed that it would be the correct place for people to give suggestions on the topic as to where I can find resources to solve my problem and to learn a thing or two. Thats all.

Comment: most of those questions are old. Some aren't and most get closed. If you're in doubt 3 users of over 3,000 reputation voted to close in the first 5 minutes of your question being open. There are _a lot_ of questions on [meta] about it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine, you just forgot the quotes.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE Field NOT IN (
    SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = '$table' 
    AND column_name LIKE 'project_images_%'
);
```

Note the quotes added to the where clause in the sub-query.

Comment: sorry if this is quite a novice question. but in a subquery. do i have to modify column_name and table_name or are those just variables mysql will recognize? for example i have a table called about and i want to make sure project images are not included when i render the form for the table as it will be done in another form

Comment: You can use a parent table.column in a sub, select * from foo where foo.id in (select id from bar where bar.related_id = foo.id)